# JFrame and ItemListener Issues

Tags: java, swing, jframe, components, itemlistener

I cannot figure out the debug for class.

As the comments say, it needs to have the user enter pizza toppings and it gives the price back. It has the code but I have no clue where to start on this debug.

Anything will help, or even if you have a working code like it would help. I want to learn it but do need help. So thank you in advance for any help/nudge in the right direction.

```
// DebugFourteen3
// User selects pizza topping and sees price
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//use correct spelling of class name
public class DebugFourteen3 extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
   JComboBox pizzaBox = new JComboBox();
   JLabel toppingList = new JLabel("Topping List");
   JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Paulos's American Pie");
   JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
   int[] pizzaPrice = {7,10,10,8,8,8,8};
   int totalPrice = 0;
   String output;
   int pizzaNum;
   public DebugFourteen3()
   {
      super("Pizza List");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(flow);
      pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
      add(toppingList);
      pizzaBox.addItem("cheese");
      pizzaBox.addItem("sausage");
      pizzaBox.addItem("pepperoni");
      pizzaBox.addItem("onion");
      pizzaBox.addItem("green pepper");
      pizzaBox.addItem("green olive");
      pizzaBox.addItem("black olive");
      add(pizzaBox);
      add(aLabel);
      add(totalprice);
   }
   public static void main(String[] arguments)
   {
      JFrame frame = new DebugFourteen3();
      frame.setSize(200, 150);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)
   {
      Object source = list.getSource();
      if(source == pizzaBox)
      {
         int pizzaNum = pizzaBox.getSelectedIndex();
         totalPrice = pizzaPrice[x];
         output = "Pizza Price $" + totalPrice;
         totPrice.setText(output);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: *"I want to learn it but do need help."*  You also need a (specific) question.  What is your question?

Comment: Identify the problem you're having and focus in on the like places it will occur...

Comment: I don't know how to fix the compile errors I am getting. I fixed all but 4 and they are in the 'public class DebugFourteen3' part, 'add(totalPrice);', it says it cannot find the symbol for 'list.getSource();' I believe specifically the list portion, and this last one says not public in component 'pizzaPrice[x]'. These are all the visible issues I am getting, sorry for confusion.

Comment: This critical information should not be in a comment but rather should be in your question. Please clarify your question by showing unambiguously in your code where the errors are occurring.

Comment: Also if your code has multiple compiler errors, then this suggests that your style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Comment: *"I don't know how to fix the compile errors I am getting"* - Ah, so you're getting compiler errors.  Add those to your question

Answer (score 0):

- `add(totalprice);` is an `int`, it can not be added to a `Container`.  Use a `JLabel`, `JTextField` or `JFormattedTextField` instead
- `public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list) {` is not a valid signature for the contractual requirements of `ItemListener`.  See the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) for the requirement method signature that will honor the contractual requirements, which will take care of at least two other errors
- `totalPrice = pizzaPrice[x];`, `x` is undefined (or more to the point, it is defined as a `private` variable in `Component` and you can reference it, I think you want `pizzaNum`

Personally, I think you will find it easier to use an `ActionListener` instead of a `ItemListener` as you only care about the change in the selected item, not the change from the old selected item to the new selected item

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
// DebugFourteen3
// User selects pizza topping and sees price
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

//use correct spelling of class name
public class DebugFourteen3 extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JComboBox pizzaBox = new JComboBox();
    JLabel toppingList = new JLabel("Topping List");
    JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Paulos's American Pie");
    JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
    int[] pizzaPrice = { 7, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8 };
    int totalPrice = 0;
    String output;
    int pizzaNum;

    public DebugFourteen3() {
        super("Pizza List");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(flow);
        pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
        add(toppingList);
        pizzaBox.addItem("cheese");
        pizzaBox.addItem("sausage");
        pizzaBox.addItem("pepperoni");
        pizzaBox.addItem("onion");
        pizzaBox.addItem("green pepper");
        pizzaBox.addItem("green olive");
        pizzaBox.addItem("black olive");
        add(pizzaBox);
        add(aLabel);
        add(totPrice);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JFrame frame = new DebugFourteen3();
        frame.setSize(200, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list) {
        Object source = list.getSource();
        if (source == pizzaBox) {
            int pizzaNum = pizzaBox.getSelectedIndex();
            totalPrice = pizzaPrice[pizzaNum];
            output = "Pizza Price $" + totalPrice;
            totPrice.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```

The mistakes was:

- When you implement an interface, you need to define all of its methods or mark the class as abstract. In your class `public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list)` method of interface ItemListener was missing. Your class has a method `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)` but  argument in this method does not match with the interface method. So modified this method's argument.
- `add(totalprice);` `totalprice` is an integer value & you cannot add it to a JFrame. Actualy you need to add `JTextField totPrice`.
- In method `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)`, variable `x` is undefined. Actually you need the index of selected item from combo to get its price from `pizzaPrice` array. So replaced `x` with `pizzaNum`.